# Linq with multiple columns while doing a trim() on a column

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, trim

I am trying to write a linq query that will allow me to do a trim on one of the columns that I am grouping by.

Here is what I have so far and it doesn't work I get 2 errors:

```
var statusGroup =
        (from r in cxt.unilists
         group r by new { r.type, r.csname.Trim() } status
         into sg
         select new ClaimListListTotalLinqPresentation
                    {
                         Type = sg.Key.type,
                         Status = sg.Key.csname,
                         ClaimCount = sg.Count(),
                         ClaimTotal = sg.Sum(x => x.claimtotal)
                    })                         
                    .Where(x => x.Type == "HOSP").ToList();
```

Errors:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

and

> 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'csname' and no extension method 'csname' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am attempting to do a trim on `r.csname`

Comment: I would think you'd do the Trim() in the select clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new { r.type, r.csname }
```

is a shortname for

```
new { type = r.type, csname = r.csname }
```

With the new property taking the name of the property used.  However, when you add  the `.Trim()`, then it's no longer a direct use of a property, so there's no default name.  What you want is:

```
new { r.type, csname = r.csname.Trim() }
```

That should solve both problems.